# Update MySQL Row When Updating Using Another Table

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I'm trying to use a trigger to update a column on my database when a row gets updated.

This is the trigger

```
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `mysql_development`.`update_translated_position`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `mysql_development`.`players_to_teams`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE players_to_teams
    INNER JOIN position_translator
    ON NEW.position = position_translator.RawPosition
    SET NEW.translated_position = position_translator.NCAAposAbbrev1;
END$$
```

I need to "calculate" the `translated_position` from the raw `position` input (in case someone gives me a non-standard position).

I think this is locking the row, because I am getting a 1096, no table used error.

I need to update the `players_to_teams` row being updated using the external `position_translator` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SET` directly rather than `UPDATE` (and therefore avoid the join altogether):

```
SET NEW.translated_position := (
  SELECT NCAAposAbbrev1 FROM position_translator WHERE RawPosition = NEW.position
);
```

Comment: @TylerDeWitt: It is the [assignment operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value).